# call index.php from another index.php of different directory

Tags: javascript, php

```
/school
/teacher
  index.php
/student
  index.php
```

How can I call `student/index.php` from `teacher/index.php`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call"?

Comment: redirect it to student/index.php

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want to include the file you can write: `include "../student/index.php";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your teacher/index.php write

```
header("Location: ../student/index.php"); // this is incase you want to go to that page
require_once('../student/index.php'); // incase you want to include that file
```

Comment: header() function works..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
require '../student/index.php';
```

This will 'call' the script. If the script has a return value, then simply make an assignment statement on the left side of the require statement.

```
$ret = require '../student/index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `teacher/index.php` use this code at top

```
header("Location: ../student/index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pecl_http (if available) and the function http_redirect.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php